# Flutter PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-video-player

when i try to play this video using this url "https://delivery517.akamai-video-content.com/hls2/01/01760/fgesr7u3hfzl_n/index-v1-a1.m3u8?t=TmRywG1Pi65jbfXWoVSj-k-gvBc8mG1onwqKjcn1gY8&s=1683131305&e=10800&f=8802758&srv=sto088&client=202.142.121.85" it throws this error but when i make a get request to this url using http using this header
{"watchsb": 'sbstream'}

i get response like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://delivery517.akamai-video-content.com/hls2/01/01760/fgesr7u3hfzl_n/seg-1-v1-a1.ts?t=LX4mGZX-kKnjzx0HxvP_pvBkRrshnHhl7VZ-9dVHUvQ&s=1683132127&e=10800&f=8802758&srv=sto088&client=202.142.121.85
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://delivery517.akamai-video-content.com/hls2/01/01760/fgesr7u3hfzl_n/seg-2-v1-a1.ts?t=LX4mGZX-kKnjzx0HxvP_pvBkRrshnHhl7VZ-9dVHUvQ&s=1683132127&e=10800&f=8802758&srv=sto088&client=202.142.121.85
#EXTINF:10.000,
https://delivery517.akamai-video-content.com/hls2/01/01760/fgesr7u3hfzl_n/seg-3-v1-a1.ts?t=LX4mGZX-kKnjzx0HxvP_pvBkRrshnHhl7VZ-9dVHUvQ&s=1683132127&e=10800&f=8802758&srv=sto088&client=202.142.121.85
#EXTINF:10.000
....
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

first i thought the problem was the headers but i am correctly sending the headers and the url to the video player

**Here's The Code**

```
class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoFile videoFile;
  final List<VideoServerResponse> servers;
  final String title;

  const VideoApp(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.videoFile,
      required this.servers});

  @override
  State<VideoApp> createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        widget.videoFile.data[0].fileUrl,
        httpHeaders: widget.videoFile.headers)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        _controller.play();

        setState(() {});
      })
      ..setLooping(true);
  }

  Widget _buildPlayerWidget(BuildContext context) {
    
    return (!_controller.value.isInitialized)
        ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
          )
        : OkVideoPlayer(
            title: widget.title,
            controller: _controller,
            videoFile: widget.videoFile,
                       servers: widget.servers,
          );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: Center(child: _buildPlayerWidget(context))),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```